# Matplotlib Subplot into Tkinter GUI window

Tags: user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter, python-3.4

I'm working on a Tkinter GUI and I was wondering if it was possible to put a Subplot into a Tkinter GUI. Any help would be appreciated as I currently have no idea.

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 3)

google = web.DataReader("GOOG", 'yahoo', start, end )

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0,0), colspan=4)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (1,0), colspan=2)

top = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0, 0), rowspan=3, colspan=4)
top.plot(google.index, google["Close"])
plt.title('Google Stock Price from 2007 - 2012')

bottom = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (3,0), rowspan=1, colspan=4)
bottom.bar(google.index, google['Volume'])
plt.title('Google Trading Volume in Millions')

plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15,8)
plt.show()
```

I'm working with something around this, but I haven't been able to place it into the GUI without it being an entirely separate window.

```
self.root2= Tk()
self.root2.geometry("600x400")
self.root2.title("Stock Visualization")
frame = Frame(self.root2)
frame.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky="s")
frame2 = Frame(self.root2)
frame2.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky = "n")
##        self.canvas=Canvas(self.root2, width=300, height=300, background='white')
##        self.canvas.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan = 4)
```

This is part of the frame, without all the labels and such around. I have that Canvas commented out where I would want the Subplot to go.

Comment: Have you seen http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html  I would point out that if you use the TkAgg backend, you _are_ using an embedding in tk

Comment: I see. so it calls it onto a Canvas. Do you have any idea how I would incorporate that into the Pandas Data Reader and such?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late, but you should try something along the lines of this

```
     fig = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi = 100)
     ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
     figcanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = root)
     plotthis(figcanvas, ax)#in this example plotthis is a function that plots the figure, ax being a graph, and figcanvas being the canvas of which the graph is being plotted to.
     figcanvas.get_tk_widget().grid()
```

Just as a little heads up, I don't think this method of doing this works in 3 yet, so as of now, I would just do it in 2 if at all possible. No clue as to why it doesn't work in 3. Hope this helps :)